# How to define nonce for style-src-attr or script-src-attr?

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm trying to lock down my pages with a content security policy (CSP).  The default CSP is too restrictive (and I cannot change the code to make it compliant, as it comes from a 3rd party), so I'm trying to define the minimal set of permissions in the CSP.  To that end, I'd like to use style-src-attr and script-src-attr.  And I'd like to use these with a nonce.  I can see how to specify the nonce for both of these in the CSP.  What I'm not sure about is how to specify the nonce for the html element (in the case of style-src-attr) and the javascript object  (in the case of script-src-attr).  I looked for an example, but couldn't find anything.  Please give an example of how this could be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled over this question in actually preparing a lecture on the topic. The answer to the question is: you cannot.

Looking at the CSP Spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#match-element-to-source-list), only script or style tags can be nonced. The `-attr` variants do not apply to stand-alone elements (script tags, style tags, or links to CSS files), as per the spec (https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-script-src-attr)

> The script-src-attr directive applies to event handlers and, if present, it will override the script-src directive for relevant checks.

Bottom line, in the current specificiation, it should not be possible to allow event handlers through nonces. It is possible to rely on `unsafe-hashes` and put the hashes of known event handlers in there, but even that is not fully supported in browser (FF and Safari lack support, see https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_csp_content-security-policy_unsafe-hashes)

Comment: Disappointing, but it's what I was suspecting.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I guess I'm kinda confused why allowing style attributes on an element that also has the correct `nonce` attribute isn't an option they could have specified?